# How to assign JSON array to a string using the SimpleJSON library in C++

Tags: c++, json

I want to assign a string with a json array.
My code is:

```
JSONArray v;
JSONObject x,y,value;
....
x[L"x"]=new JSONValue((double)(i));
x[L"y"]=new JSONValue((double)(i));
value[L"value"]=new JSONValue((char*)(data));
v.push_back(new JSONValue(x));
v.push_back(new JSONValue(y));
v.push_back(new JSONValue(value));

all[i]->fruits->append(new JSONValue(v)); //error here,fruits is a string type
```

fruits is a string defined inside all.

I tried using push_back too but Its not working.

Comment: What the heck is an `l` in this code? What is `fruits`?

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: I am using simple json libray https://github.com/MJPA/SimpleJSON/tree/master/src

Comment: What exactly do you expect "appending" an array to a string to do? It's like saying you want to add 5 to apple.

Comment: I want to save the json array in a database so I have to save the json array to a string to save it.

Comment: I would, if I were you, reconsider your choice to use a library that requires such flippant use of `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `fruits` is a `std::wstring` you can use the `Stringigy()` member of `JSONValue` to do handle the conversion.

```
all[i]->fruits->append(JSONValue(v).Stringify());
```

Comment: thanks it worked.do i have to delete any of the object.As i am running in a big for loop my process is getting aborted.I am getting pointed to deallocate(pointer_p,size_type).

Comment: For every `new` there needs to be a `delete`. At what point you call `delete` is really up to how you have organized your program and the requirements of the libraries you use.